# How to get external data into content element in Typo3 without extension?

Tags: mysql, typo3

I want to output text from an external source within a Typo3 content element. The external source can be fields in table within a mysql database (preferred) but not the same the typo3 installation is running on. It also can be a txt file on the webserver.

Is there a simple way in Typoscript or with a content element to do this without building an extension (kickstarter seems not to work in version 6) and manipulation of TCA?

Any alternative way that bypasses typo3 (url?) also considered. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot fetch content from external databases or locations with TypoScript, and with the TYPO3 API you cannot connect to more than one database at once.

You could use EXT:extension_builder (the "new" kickstarter) and create an extension. Then, add a command controller (http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki/CommandControllerInSchedulerTask) that connects to your external database (using e.g. mysqli commands), fetches the data and stores it in the TYPO3 database.

The command controller can be used as a Scheduler job in TYPO3.

Or if you want to display the data directly, add a frontend plugin, fetch the data and render it on-the-fly. Please keep in mind that this can result in weak performance.

Comment: Lorenz, thanks. I finally found a plugin called dbtable to htmltable that allows for very simple sql requests. It seems one cannot write into the db but that is fine for me